# How to remove Disabled account in Windows PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, powershell-2.0

I have PowerShell script which access the AD users and insert into the SharePoint list.
Now the problem is some of the accounts are disabled or not active. I am using the following PowerShell script in the windows task scheduler which do the job in an interval. Can anyone Help me to figure out What I suppose to do in this script to filter only active accounts?

```
#if not already added  
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {  
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"  
}  

$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("https://portal.company.gov.sa/");  
$ServiceContext = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext]::GetContext($site);  

#Get UserProfileManager from the My Site Host Site context  
$ProfileManager = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($ServiceContext)  
$AllProfiles = $ProfileManager.GetEnumerator()  

# Open SharePoint List  
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb "https://my.gac.gov.sa/"
  
$spData = $spWeb.GetList("Lists/EmployeesDirectory/")  
$spDepartments = $spWeb.GetList("Lists/Departments/")  
$total=0;
$withErros=0;
foreach($profile in $AllProfiles) 
{  
    try 
    {

      
        $DisplayName = $profile.DisplayName  
        $WorkEmail = $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::WorkEmail]  
        $AccountName = $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::AccountName]  
        $Department = $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::Department]  
        $Position = $profile.JobTitle

        $LastName = $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::LastName] 
        $FirstName = $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::FirstName] 

        $FullName=  "$FirstName $LastName"
    
        $PreferredName = $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::PreferredName]  
        $WorkPhone =$profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::WorkPhone]
 
        $Manager = $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::Manager]
       $JobTitleArabic=$profile["JobTitleArabic"];
      

     if($Department -ine '' -and $Manager -ine ''){
       $total++;
   
       $departmnetItem = $spDepartments.Items | Where {$_["FF_TitleEn"] -eq $Department}

   
        # Add properties to this list item  
        $user=$spWeb.EnsureUser($AccountName);
     
    
         write-host $DisplayName "|"  $AccountName "|" $Department "|" $Position "|" $PreferredName "|" $WorkPhone "|" $Manager ;   

         if($user.ID -gt 0)
         {

             #Query to filter List Items which contains user account

             $SPQuery = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
             $Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FF_Emlpoyee' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='User'>$($user.ID)</Value></Eq></Where>"
             $SPQuery.Query=$Query

             #Filter List Items by Query
             $ListItems = $spData.GetItems($SPQuery)

  
            if($ListItems.Count -gt 0)
            {
                $newItem=$ListItems[0];
            }
            else
            {
                #Create a new item  
                $newItem = $spData.Items.Add()  
            }
    
    
            $newItem["FF_Emlpoyee"] = $user.ID; 
            # $newItem["FF_UserID"] = $user.ID;  
            $newItem["Title"] = $PreferredName
            if($WorkPhone -ine '')
            {
                $newItem["FF_ExtensionNumber"] = $WorkPhone 
            }
       
            try
            {
                if($Manager -ine $null)
                {
                    $userManager=$spWeb.EnsureUser($Manager); 
        
                    $newItem["FF_Manager"] = $userManager.ID  
                }
            }
            catch
            { 

                write-host -ForegroundColor Red  "Manager Not Found fro : " $user 
            }
        
      
           $newItem["FF_Position"] =  $Position
           IF($JobTitleArabic -ine '')
           {
            $newItem["FF_PositionAr"] = $JobTitleArabic

           }
          
           
           $newItem["FF_FullNameAr"] = $FullName
           $newItem["FF_Department"] = $departmnetItem.ID 
           $newItem.Update()   
      
           Write-Host "---------------------------------";
        }
        $user=$null
    
    } 
    }
    catch   
    { 

        write-host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception 
        $withErros+=1
     }
}

Write-Host "Total: " $total;
Write-Host "withErros: " $withErros
```

Comment: How are your SP user profiles getting created/updated/synced - AD import or MS identity management? Is their disabled status getting synced to sharepoint?

Comment: I am using this script which is just importing AD accounts.